# How to handle "Underscore" in filename - Debian 11

Tags: debian, terminal, sudo

I'm using the terminal.
Im in "usr/local/myfantasticfolder".
There is a file called "my_fantastic_file.sh".

I want to run the following command:

```
sudo ./my_fantastic_file.sh
```

It then says "no such file or directory".

I have another file inside "usr/local/myfantasticfolder".
Its called "myprettyfile.sh".
When I run `sudo ./myprettyfile.sh` it works.

I have the feeling the underscores in the filename "my_fantastic_file" are the issue.
Anyone got an idea how I can solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Which shell are you using? The underscores are almost certainly not the issue. Include outputs of `ls -l` on the mentioned paths.

Comment: or it's the error message of a command inside the script file.

Comment: Look if the shebang-line is correct. Unix uses linefeed line delimiters. If the file was created using windows, chances are that lines are terminated with CRLF.

Comment: sudo does not say `no such file or directory`. If its arg file is not found, it says:
`sudo: ./my_fantastic_file.sh: command not found`.
Your script has the problem. And if it does not state a filename, that confirms that there is a CR in the command, so the message overwrites the name.

Comment: What's the output of `env LC_ALL=C sed -ne l -e q < my_fantastic_file.sh`?

Comment: What's the precise error message? I suspect you're missing (at least) part of the beginning

Comment: @Paul_Pedant that was it, thanks a bunch! :)

Answer (score 0):

Not the underscores.

Assuming that your current working directory contains the file in question this error implies that the file does not have executable permissions on it (there can be other causes but they are somewhat obscure). You can confirm this using `ls -l` and check for 'x' in the permissions string. You can fix this with `chmod u+x my_fantastic_file.sh`